# how to display in models img to html in django

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-templates

I tried to display to html changeable profile image with admin. can someone explain please

models in Portfolio app :

```
class ProfileImage(models.Model):
  profile = models.ImageField(("Profile image"), upload_to=None, height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=None)
```

this is base html in template folder (i tried this one) :

```
<img src="{{ portfolio.models.ProfileImage.progile.url }}" alt="profile"><br />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first configure your model to store profile pictures. Your **ProfileImage** model looks correct, but you need to specify where the images should be uploaded using the **upload_to** argument of **ImageField**.

Include the model in your admin form by using a **ModelForm** or manually adding it to the admin's **fields** list.

In your HTML template, you can display the image using the url attribute of your template's **ImageField** object.

You have an error in your HTML above, it should be profile.url and not portfolio.models.ProfileImage.profile.url:

```
<img src="{{ profile.image.url }}" alt="profile">
```